# Reduce multiple re rendering of components in React

Tags: javascript, performance, html, react.js, jsx

Following is my working application that contains a Search Container, a Sorting Container and a listing Container.

Based on Search and Sort the listing data changes in the listing container.

The application works fine though I noticed in my Search container whenever I am changing the input value in an input box, select component is re rendering and vice versa(check console).

Is there any pattern or modification I can do to minimise the re renders in the application ?

Working Demo - https://ojlrd.csb.app/

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/rerender-ojlrd?file=/src/index.js

---

Code -

**Page.js**

```
const Page = () => {
  const [pageData, setPageData] = useState({
    search: {},
    sort: {
      sortBy: ''
    }
  });

  const getData = useCallback((type, data) => {
    setPageData(prevVal => {
      return {
        ...prevVal,
        [type]: {...data}

      }
    })
  }, [setPageData]);
  

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <SearchContainer getData={getData} />
      <SortingContainer getData={getData} />
      <ListingContainer urlData={pageData} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

**SearchContainer.js**

```
const SearchContainer = ({
  getData = () => {}
}) => {
  const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState({
    search1: '',
    search2: '13',
    search3: '',
    search4: '44'
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getData('search', searchData);
  }, [searchData, getData]);

  const eventHandler = e => {
    setSearchData(prevVal => {
      return {
        ...prevVal,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="container-search">
      <h3>Search container</h3>
      <div className="container-search-actions">
        <Input
          initialValue=''
          label='Input 1'
          name="search1"
          eventHandler={eventHandler}
        />
        <Select
          label='Select 2'
          name="search2"
          options={[
            {label: 'Label 11', value: '11'},
            {label: 'Label 12', value: '12'},
            {label: 'Label 13', value: '13'},
            {label: 'Label 14', value: '14'}
          ]}
          selectedValue='13'
          eventHandler={eventHandler}
        />
        <Input
          initialValue=''
          label='Input 3'
          name="search3"
          eventHandler={eventHandler}
        />
        <Select
          label='Select 4'
          name="search4"
          options={[
            {label: 'Label 41', value: '41'},
            {label: 'Label 42', value: '42'},
            {label: 'Label 43', value: '43'},
            {label: 'Label 44', value: '44'}
          ]}
          selectedValue='44'
          eventHandler={eventHandler}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchContainer;
```

**SortingContainer.js**

```
const SortingContainer = ({
  getData = () => {}
}) => {
  const [sortData, setSortData] = useState({
    sortBy: 'desc'
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    getData('sort', sortData);
  }, [sortData, getData]);

  const eventHandler = e => {
    setSortData(prevVal => {
      return {
        ...prevVal,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    })
  }


  return (
    <div className="container-sorting">
      <Select 
        label='Sort By'
        name='sortBy'
        options={[
          {label: 'Ascending', value: 'asc'},
          {label: 'Descending', value: 'desc'}
        ]}
        selectedValue='desc'
        eventHandler={eventHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SortingContainer;
```

**ListingContainer.js**

```
const ListingContainer = ({ urlData }) => {
  const createURL = (urlData) => {
    const { search, sort } = urlData;
    let url = "/api?";

    [search, sort].forEach((element) => {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(element)) {
        url += `&${key}=${value}`;
      }
    });
    return url;
  };
  return (
    <div className="container-listing">
      This is a listing container
      <p>URL Formed - </p>
      <p className="bold">{createURL(urlData)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListingContainer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding a `memo` wrapper around the components' `export` statements, then passing in a compare function that returns `true`. The components were re-rendering each time the `eventHandler` function was re-created when the state of the parent changed on each input.

Since you pass no dynamic data in, there is no reason for these components to re-render except when their own state is updated.

[See a working example here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/48qge)

**Input.js**

```
...
export default memo(Input, () => true);
```

**Select.js**

```
...
export default memo(Select, () => true);
```

[Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)